# Casting 2D array with Pybind11

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, cmake, pybind11

I'm creating Python bindings for a C++ library that I have header/lib files for, but this function that takes a 2D array as an argument is not converted automatically by Pybind11. How do I convert this argument correctly?

The header file declares this function like

```
class __declspec(dllimport) SomeClass {
    public:
        void function(uint32_t arg1, uint32_t arg2, float matrix[3][3]);
```

and I'm binding it like

```
py::class_<SomeClass>(m, "_SomeClass", "SomeClass")
    .def("function", &SomeClass::function,
    py::arg("arg1"), py::arg("arg2"), py::arg("matrix"))
```

`python setup.py bdist_wheel` outputs the following (commenting the `function` binding builds the wheel fine)

```
C:\Users\joona\git\someproject\pybind11\include\pybind11\cast.h(1931,1): error C2664:  'Return pybind11::cpp_function::{ctor}::<lambda_b1f1895366c1273186f52810f5be9d13>::operator ()(Class *,uint32_t ,uint32_t ,float (*)[3]) const': cannot convert argument 4 from 'float *' to 'float (*)[3]' [C:\Users\joona\git\someproject\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\someproject.vcxproj]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with `std::array`:

```cpp
class __declspec(dllimport) SomeClass {
    public:
        void function(uint32_t arg1, uint32_t arg2,
                      std::array<std::array<float,3>,3> matrix);
...
};
```

pybind will know how to convert this to a 2d list.
Also, inside your cpp code, the access is the same as for `float[3][3]`.

EDIT:

following from your comment, I think you could use something like this (see [from pybind documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/classes.html#binding-lambda-functions)):

```cpp
py::class_<SomeClass>(m, "SomeClass")
   .def("function", [](SomeClass& sc, uint32_t arg1, uint32_t arg2,
                       std::array<std::array<float,3>,3> m)
        {
            float M[3][3] = {{m[0][0], m[0][1], m[0][2]},
                             {m[1][0], m[1][1], m[1][2]},
                             {m[2][0], m[2][1], m[2][2]}};
            return sc.function(arg1, arg2, M);
        });
```

Here I assume that the matrix is only an input for the function; you can copy back the result to the std array if it is also output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately I don't have access to the C++ code (only the .h and .lib). I suppose I could wrap the library in my own C++ code, but I was hoping to find a less messy solution.

Comment: @Joona I edited my answer accordingly, hope this is what you meant

Comment: Yep, that's it (or at least it compiles). Thank you!